# What is the dimension of Karuta cards?

Tags: culture, chihayafuru

Chihayafuru is an anime about card game called Karuta where players compete to touch the right card based on the poem being read. Chihayafuru wikia [lists all 100 of the poem](http://chihayafuru.wikia.com/wiki/Ogura_Hyakunin_Isshu). However, I can't find the dimension of the card they use in the game. What is the dimension of the card used by Chihaya in the matches? Like how many cm x how many cm? If possible, the thickness of the card too.

Comment: Thickness wise i would assume it's the same as Yu-Gi-Oh, Pokemon, Cardfight Vanguard, Magic: The Gathering and Cards Against Humanity Cards. at least i assume they are all the same, they look and feel the same thickness wise

Comment: [This is the best image I could find for thickness](http://www.japanese-vintage.org/images/japan_karuta_antique_2016apr276.jpg)

Comment: google: "karuta card size" -> http://wakjapan.com/chanoyu-karuta/, other sizes stated on other sites are american playing cards **or** larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Competition cards are 74x53mm (~2.9x2.1 inches) in size, and made from "pasteboard". Reference: [Japanese Wikipedia article on karuta](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BE%E4%BA%BA%E4%B8%80%E9%A6%96#.E3.81.8B.E3.82.8B.E3.81.9F).  The pasteboard used to make Japanese playing cards tends to be thicker than what we are familiar with in the West for cards. It's called 厚紙 (atsugami = thick paper) and can be quite thick -- I have some Japanese playing cards that are 0.4mm thick, which is thicker than Western plastic playing cards, and I've seen images of atsugami that look quite a bit thicker.

Alas I don't know exactly how thick karuta competition cards are since I never held any.